# Как вывести ошибки в Vue после валидации от Laravel Request?

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js, request

Хочу сделать валидацию формы в Vue компоненте. Создал request и при не успешной провекри мне возвращает JSON [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните плз как с ним работать дальше. Мне необходимо под каждым input вывести свое сообщение об ошибке.Вот сам компнент с формой.

```
<template>
    <div>
        
        <form @submit.prevent="submit">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task-title">Task name</label>
                    <input v-model="task.title"
                           type="text"
                           name="title"
                           class="form-control"
                           id="task-title">
                </div>

            <div v-if="errors" v-for="category in errors">
                <div class="m-alert m-alert--outline alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert" v-for="error in category">
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task-description">Task description</label>
                    <textarea name="description"
                              class="form-control"
                              id="task-description"
                              rows="3"
                              v-model="task.description"></textarea>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update task</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {

        props: [
            'oldtask'
        ],

        data() {
            return {
                task: {
                    id: '',
                    title: '',
                    description: ''
                },
                errors: {},
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.getDate();
        },

        methods: {

            getDate() {
                this.task = this.oldtask;
                // console.log(this.oldtask);
            },

            submit() {
                axios.patch(`/api/tasks/update`, {
                    id: this.oldtask.id,
                    title: this.task.title,
                    description: this.task.description
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        window.location.href = `/`;
                    }).catch(error => {
                    if (error.response.status === 422) {
                        console.log(error.response.data.errors);
                    }
                })

            }
        },
        
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<template>
            <div>
                
                <form @submit.prevent="submit">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="task-title">Task name</label>
                            <input v-model="task.title"
                                   type="text"
                                   name="title"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   id="task-title">
                            <div v-show="errors.title">{{errors.title}}</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="task-description">Task description</label>
                            <textarea name="description"
                                      class="form-control"
                                      id="task-description"
                                      rows="3"
                                      v-model="task.description"></textarea>
                            <div v-show="errors.description">{{errors.description}}</div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update task</button>
                </form>

            </div>
        </template>
        <script>

            export default {

                props: [
                    'oldtask'
                ],

                data() {
                    return {
                        task: {
                            id: '',
                            title: '',
                            description: ''
                        },
                        errors: {
                            title: '',
                            description: ''
                        },
                    }
                },

                mounted() {
                    this.getDate();
                },

                methods: {

                    getDate() {
                        this.task = this.oldtask;
                        // console.log(this.oldtask);
                    },

                    submit() {
                        this.errors.title = ''
                        this.errors.description = ''
                        axios.patch(`/api/tasks/update`, {
                            id: this.oldtask.id,
                            title: this.task.title,
                            description: this.task.description
                        })
                            .then(response => {
                                window.location.href = `/`;
                            }).catch(error => {
                            if (error.response.status === 422) {
                                console.log(error.response.data.errors);
                                this.errors.title = error.response.data.errors.title
                                this.errors.description = error.response.data.errors.description
                            }
                        })

                    }
                },
                
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: не работает(, вроде как в методе все ок, а вот шаблон не грузит из-за 

<div v-show="errors.description">{{error.description}}</div>

Comment: Там опечатка, errors.description. Читайте внимательно

Comment: только хотел написать), да все оке работает, большое спасибо (хоть понятно стало).

Comment: Буду благодарен за галочку